# RefreshIndicator Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, pull-to-refresh

Does the [RefreshIndicator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RefreshIndicator-class.html) only work with Scrollable or ListView-related widgets? I wish to use it with a Container inside a Scaffoled and use a GestureRecognizer whereby upon pulling down it refreshes.

I tried to use RefreshIndicator in my code enclosing a Container but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add SingleChildScrollView in between works fine for me.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: () {},
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            child: Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Text('Hello World'),
              ),
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }

}
```